# Remove div on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this HTML structure:

```
 <div class="shadow"></div>
<div id="slide_img">
  <ul class="clearfix">
   <li><img src="themes/company/img/01.png"></li>
   <li><img src="themes/company/img/02.png"></li> 
   <li><img src="themes/company/img/03.png"></li> 
   <li><img src="themes/company/img/04.png"></li> 
   <li><img src="themes/company/img/05.png"></li> 
   <li><img src="themes/company/img/01.png"></li>  
 </ul>
</div>
```

shadow div on my img and get opacity effect. But when hover on img, remove this shadow div.

shadow CSS:

```
.shadow {
  background: none no-repeat scroll center center #000000;
  height: 250px;
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0.7;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 1838px;
  z-index:2;
}
```

How can i do this via jQuery?

Answer (score 7):

Put your `.shadow` div *inside* `#slide_img` and you can do it with pure CSS:

```css
#slide_img:hover .shadow{
    display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slide_img img").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
    $('.shadow').toggle(e.type=='mouseenter');
});
```

Comment: $("#slide_img img").on is not a function via Firebug.

Comment: That just means your version of jQuery is to old, you'll need version 1.7+ for on(), and right now you should probably be using 1.8.2.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to temporary hide this use

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#slide_img img').hover(
        function(){
            // When hover the #slide_img img hide the div.shadow
            $('div.shadow').hide();
        },function(){
            // When out of hover the #slide_img img show the div.shadow
            $('div.shadow').show();
        }
    );
});
```

ex.on [jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/PrD3w/)

else you want to absolutely remove this use

```
$('#slide_img img').hover(function(){$('div.shadow').remove();});
```

Comment: thank you.  i want ask to you one question. My shadow div on all slide img, well, when hover 1 img, remove all shadow on images. i want give shadow div on slide_img img but not stable width my images.

Comment: I do not understand what you want to do.
Did you want to make the div.shadow show on only hover one and hide the others?